# Quokka.js(Wallaby.js) is unable to find jquery: $ is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, wallaby.js, quokka.js

I have a small js project which runs without an issue. I wanted to try out Quokka.js(Wallaby.js) and see how it goes.

When I have enabled Quokka in vscode, it showed an error for $ is not defined for

```
$.ajaxSetup({ async: true, type: "GET" });
```

Is there a way to tell Quokka.js where to find jQuery?

**My server config:**

I am using nginx as the back end for my server and I initialize jQuery and script js in html file with

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="./scripts/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="./scripts/script.js"></script>
```

**Quokka.js file configured by default to:**

```
{"pro":false}
```

**Quokka.js Console Output**
​

```
Quokka #1 (node: v6.10.3)​​​​
​​​​
​​$ is not defined​​
  at scripts/quokka.js:184:0​
```

**Editor and OS:**

Visual Studio Code v1.14.0

CentOS Linux 7 (Core)

Quokka.js page: https://quokkajs.com/